# Implementation of Matlab matrix inverse function in C++ with Eigen

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

So I need to re-write matrix right-handed division from Matlab to C++:

```
At = (xPow*yPow')/(yPow*yPow');
```

I mocked some matrices:

```
>> xPow*yPow'

ans =

0.0004    0.0040    0.0004    0.0004
0.0014    0.0263    0.0014    0.0014
0.0004    0.0012    0.0004    0.0004
0.0012    0.0053    0.0012    0.0012
```

and

```
>> yPow*yPow'

ans =

0.0001    0.0004    0.0001    0.0001
0.0004    0.0256    0.0004    0.0004
0.0001    0.0004    0.0001    0.0001
0.0001    0.0004    0.0001    0.0001
```

Matlab returns same result for `(xPow*yPow')/(yPow*yPow')` as well as `xPow*yPow' * inv(yPow*yPow')`.

```
>> xPow*yPow' * inv(yPow*yPow')

ans =

36.1259    0.1127  -30.3163   -2.6999
40.6472    0.8810  -19.7529  -11.8430
-1.5578   -0.0182   12.1397   -7.0087
124.4466    0.0594 -130.0163   16.6710

>> At = (xPow*yPow')/(yPow*yPow')

At =

 36.1259    0.1127  -30.3163   -2.6999
 40.6472    0.8810  -19.7529  -11.8430
 -1.5578   -0.0182   12.1397   -7.0087
124.4466    0.0594 -130.0163   16.6710
```

Eigen library has function `.inverse()` so I thought I might use it to implement division of those matrices:

```
xyPowMult(0,0) = 0.0004;
xyPowMult(0,1) = 0.0040;
xyPowMult(0,2) = 0.0004;
xyPowMult(0,3) = 0.0004;
xyPowMult(1,0) = 0.0014;
xyPowMult(1,1) = 0.0263;
xyPowMult(1,2) = 0.0014;
xyPowMult(1,3) = 0.0014;
xyPowMult(2,0) = 0.0004;
xyPowMult(2,1) = 0.0012;
xyPowMult(2,2) = 0.0004;
xyPowMult(2,3) = 0.0004;
xyPowMult(3,0) = 0.0012;
xyPowMult(3,1) = 0.0053;
xyPowMult(3,2) = 0.0012;
xyPowMult(3,3) = 0.0012;

yyPowMult(0,0) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(0,1) = 0.0004;
yyPowMult(0,2) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(0,3) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(1,0) = 0.0004;
yyPowMult(1,1) = 0.0256;
yyPowMult(1,2) = 0.0004;
yyPowMult(1,3) = 0.0004;
yyPowMult(2,0) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(2,1) = 0.0004;
yyPowMult(2,2) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(2,3) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(3,0) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(3,1) = 0.0004;
yyPowMult(3,2) = 0.0001;
yyPowMult(3,3) = 0.0001;

AtTemp = xyPowMult * yyPowMult.inverse();

cout << " x*y' " << endl;
cout << xyPowMult << endl << endl;

cout << " y*y' " << endl;
cout << yyPowMult << endl << endl;

cout << " x*y' * inv(y*y') " << endl;
cout << xyPowMult * yyPowMult.inverse() << endl << endl;
```

And the console outcome shows different result:

```
 x*y'
0.0004  0.004 0.0004 0.0004
0.0014 0.0263 0.0014 0.0014
0.0004 0.0012 0.0004 0.0004
0.0012 0.0053 0.0012 0.0012

 y*y'
0.0001 0.0004 0.0001 0.0001
0.0004 0.0256 0.0004 0.0004
0.0001 0.0004 0.0001 0.0001
0.0001 0.0004 0.0001 0.0001

 x*y' * inv(y*y')
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND
-1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND -1.#IND
```

So my questions are:

1. Why the result is different?
2. How can I implement matrix "slash" division with usage of Eigen?
3. If not Eigen, then could you suggest any simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues. First, as Ilya Popov pointed out, `y*y'` is singular. Actually, so is `x*y'`. Second, matlab's `\` [operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) actually solves a system of linear equations (Ax=B --> solves for x). Solving singular (or near singular) matrices using naive methods (e.g. `inverse()`) is not usually a good idea.

So to do the same with Eigen, you would set up the equations to solve and use the solution ([intro](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html)). However, you would choose a specific algorithm based on prior knowledge. For example,

```
A.fullPivLu().solve(b);
```

would give you `A\b` using LU.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the last two rows of `y*y'` are identical. The matrix is singular (as is any matrix like `v*v'`). Such a matrix does not have an inverse. So you cannot expect any meaningful result here. Strange that Matlab produces anything. Are you sure your formula is correct?

Comment: Might it be caused by the fact I just inserted numbers by myself to C++ and in Matlab they are aquired from proper multiplication. What Matlab displays is only an approximation which I've rewriten to C++. In Matlab numbers after 4th number might be different but I have rewritten only 4 so I created singular matrix?

Comment: Yes, can be. Note that if the matrix is close to singular, (aka *ill-conditioned*, having a large condition number), then even smallest errors in its coefficients can lead to large errors to the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

Eigen::MatrixXd inv_eigen (Eigen::MatrixXd m)
{
    // Matlab: inv(X) = X^(-1) = X\speye(size(X))
    return m.fullPivLu().solve(Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(m.rows(), m.cols()));
}
```

Result:

```
X = 3×3

  1     0     2
 -1     5     0
  0     3    -9

Matlab inv(X)

  0.8824   -0.1176    0.1961
  0.1765    0.1765    0.0392
  0.0588    0.0588   -0.0980

Eigen inv(X)

  0.882353  -0.117647   0.196078
  0.176471   0.176471   0.0392157
  0.0588235  0.0588235 -0.0980392
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).